# Is there any DGEMM-type einsum in python?

Tags: python, numpy, blas, numpy-einsum

In `DGEMM` http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1.html#gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1
one can do `C = alpha * A.B + beta*C`

In `eimsum`, there is `ij,jk->ik` (or more general indices) for `A.B`. Is there any efficient way to incorporate `alpha` and `beta*C`, presumbly `A` and `B` are general-rank arrays? or Do I need to write several lines of operations with `np.dot` for `alpha,beta` and `np.add` for `beta*C`?

I tried

```
na = nb = nc = nd = 50
A = np.random.random((na,nb))
B = np.random.random((nb,nc))
C = np.random.random((na,nc))
np.einsum('ab,bc + ac ->ac',A,B)
```

got
`ValueError: invalid subscript '+' in einstein sum subscripts string, subscripts must be letters`

It seems `scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm` can do it, but only for rank-2 array https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm.html

Comment: 'bc + ac' does not belong in an `einsum` string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any way of incorporating `alpha A.B + beta C` into `einsum` string, or I should write additional lines, as `np.dot`, `np.add`?

Comment: einsum can take care of the batched dot (so can matmul). Broadcasting should handle the sum.